# Perform coordinated gorutines in Go

Tags: go

I would like to know how to coordinate routines in Go. A real case would be to coordinate two resources obtained through a request http. For example in node Nodejs would solve this with: `Promise.all [service1, service2]`

```
func request(c chan bool, ms time.Duration, val bool) {
    time.Sleep(ms * time.Millisecond)
    c <- val
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan bool, 2)
    go request(c, 1000, true)
    go request(c, 0, false)
    first, second := <-c, <-c
    fmt.Println(first, second) // output false true

}
```

The first one to be resolved is placed over the others, but how can I identify each one?

Thanks for you time.

Comment: You can't solve it in NodeJS at all, it's single-threaded.

Comment: Yes of course, I wanted to express only the idea, not the low level behavior, u suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 2 channels. They will still run concurrently, and you can keep track of which is which.

```
func request(c chan bool, ms time.Duration, val bool) {
    time.Sleep(ms * time.Millisecond)
    c <- val
}

func main() {
    c1 := make(chan bool)
    c2 := make(chan bool)

    go request(c1, 1000, true)
    go request(c2, 0, false)
    first := <-c1
    second := <-c2
    fmt.Println(first, second) // output false true

}
```

Comment: It really depends on the problem you are solving, for the sample as presented here, this way is likely the most simple. If you need to scale this up to N requests, you will probably need a different way to keep track of them. One example would be to use a single channel, and pass a unique ID into the `go request` function call, then use that same ID along with the result when you push it on to the channel to return.